# Button animation doesn't stop

Tags: android

I apply this animation to a button (RelativeLayout) while the user hold or move (while is pressed) its touch:

```
ScaleAnimation start = new ScaleAnimation(1, 1.2f, 1, 1.2f, 0x1, 0.5f, 0x1, 0.5f);
final ScaleAnimation end = new ScaleAnimation(1.2f, 1, 1.2f, 1, 0x1, 0.5f, 0x1, 0.5f);

            end.setDuration(600); 
            start.setDuration(600);
            button.startAnimation(start);
            button.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    button.startAnimation(end);
                }

            }, 600);
```

When the user releases the button, another animation must be called:

```
TranslateAnimation translateOut = new TranslateAnimation(0, -width, 1, 1);
            translateOut.setDuration(600);
            button.clearAnimation();
            button.startAnimation(translateOut);
            button.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
```

It works as it should, but the problem is that the button appears and desappears (flashes) at the users last touch position.

I already tried this codes to try to fix it (and created a flag to know if the start/end animation is running), but none of them worked:

```
start.cancel();
end.cancel();
start/end.setFillAfter/Before(true);
button.clearAnimation();
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting your button invisible right after you start the animation, so your button is invisible when the animation is running. Try to use an AnimationListener to set the visibility to invisible when the animation is over.

```
    start.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```